# Does the content stream from WiFi directly to Chromecast, or from WiFi to Android to Chromecast?

Tags: google-cast

Does the content stream from WiFi directly to Chromecast, or from WiFi to Android (or any other device) to Chromecast?

I know that the other devices can be used to control the Chromecast, but I just want to know whether say you can stream directly from your mobile due say to battery life.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The mobile device is only used for the initial **content discovery** phase where the user selects a video stream to watch. Once playback is initiated, the Chromecast device connects to the internet over WiFi and downloads the stream data without requiring the mobile device to be turned on.

[image: Data-flow on Chromecast]

More details available on the official **[Chromecast developer site](https://developers.google.com/cast/)**.

Comment: This is true for all video casting using this device and is done to save battery life and allow playback to continue without a device and to be controlled by other devices. Not the case for Tab casting which encodes and streams the contents of the tab.

Comment: Does it mean that internet data will be used twice; i.e. One stream to device and other strream to Chromecast? If yes, then is there a way to prevent & if no then, how can we jump/pause video in the mobile?

Comment: This is not true anymore, you NEED ANY SORT of internet connection all the time. Chromecasts pings some servers while you are connected to it (even if you are locally sharing your screen) and, as far my tests go, it uses around 1MB every 3 or 4 minutes. So those pings are really loaded with something.

Comment: @samul Interesting indeed! if you manage to trace the contents or the destination, of these periodic "pings" please do update the above answer with the details.