# Chromecast functionality

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, android-wifi, chromecast

This is regarding the functionality of Google Chromecast. Consider a scenario where I'm playing a YouTube video in my Android mobile. I've an old TV to which I've attached the Chromecast dongle. The TV and my mobile phone are in the same WiFi network.
What I understand, when I tap on "Cast" icon in YouTube app of my mobile, it sends a request to YouTube server to stream media to my Chromecast dongle (which is already registered). So, basically, it is not streaming directly from my mobile phone. From my phone I'm instructing YouTube to send media to one of my other registered device. This explains why the video continues to play even if send YouTube app to background.
My question is, if that is the case, then why is it necessary to have Chromecast and my mobile phone to be in the same Wi-Fi network? I can send "Cast" request from my office network and YouTube should start streaming videos to my TV connected to home network. What am I missing here? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You are sending some meta information about the video you are watching to the Chromecast and the Chromecast is fetching and playing the video from Youtube. In the most home setups Youtube would have no chance to connect to your Chromecast and send a file to it.

So for your devices to exchange these meta information they need to be in the same WiFi network.

Comment: So, it is the request going from Chromecast to YouTube and not the other way around (besides media content)? If that's the case then how does Chromecast understands what information does it has to put in a request? I assume, there must be kind of hard coded application for media content streaming. But what about third party applications not doing any media streaming? Let's say I want to write an app to control volume of Chromecast. AFAIK, the HTML5 app will be running on a server and it will decide the control logic.. please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please see the response to this [stackoverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875596/does-the-content-stream-from-wifi-directly-to-chromecast-or-from-wifi-to-androi) for a flow chart and a link to the google developers site.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is the discovery task which, based on the methods used, requires being on the same network. More importantly, the model is to cast content to a TV and doing that when you are not in front of a TV doesn't really make much sense, at least in the large majority of the cases (there is no point for me to cast something to my home TV when I am at work). As was shown at Google I/O this year, we will support a case that a "guest" can participate in casting without being on the local network but that would also requires proximity to the cast device.